# Trying to scrape data using selenium>

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a jpg out of this code using selenium. I've managed 
 to find the links to click to get where my jpg is located. (dumb luck! 
 I'm new to selenium). All the the windows open as it clicks along. It's 
 really slow, compared to Scrapy, so if anyone can tell me a faster way 
 that would be great.

The website I'm trying to scrape is www.rosegal.com. The category 
 I'm scraping is the plus size tank-top. This first page has 60 product 
 on it. If you click these product it takes you to a product page where 
 you choose the size, color, and quantity you want.

Each color has it's own images, so what I want to do is click on the first 
 color, scrape that first large image associated with that color then the 
 second color scrape that image and so on.

I've clicked my way to the data I want to scrape. I've imported 
 selenium. I called in chromedriver. Named driver, I've loaded up the url 
 I want to start with and clicked on the product I want to scrape, then I 
 clicked on the color that my jpg is in and now I'm ready to get my jpg.

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    chrome_path = r"C:/Users/daver/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 
    (4)/chromedriver.exe"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

   driver.get("https://www.rosegal.com/plus-size-tank-tops-482/")

   driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//* 
   [@id="js_proList"]/ul[1]/li[1]/div/div/p""").click()

   #This is what I tried this to get my jpg:   

  image1_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//* 
  [@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li[1]/img""")

  print("image1_element")
  print(image1_element)

  image1_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//* 
  [@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li[2]/img""")

  print("image2_element")
  print(image2_element)

  image1_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//* 
  [@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li[3]/img""")

  print("image3_element")
  print(image3_element)





   **This is the code the jpg is embedded:**

<div id="js_zoom_img" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">  
    <img data-zoomimg="https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product- 
    pic/Clothing/2019/06/18/source-img/20190618173639_71567.jpg"
```

**Trying to get this jpg:**

https://gloimg.rglcdn.com/rosegal/pdm-product- 
pic/Clothing/2019/06/18/source-img/20190618173639_71567.jpg

Also trying to get back to the page with the 60 products on it so I can 
scrape the other products.

Comment: Sorry about duplicating some of the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help you to click on each color and print all images associated to it.

```
#To click on each color
Colors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='attr-choose clearfix goods_property_color']//a")

for color in Colors:
    print("Clicking on color: ",color.get_attribute('data-value'))
    color.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #now collect all the image urls for the color
    images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='goods_thumb_content']//li")
    print("Total images",len(images))
    for image in images:
        print(image.get_attribute('data-bigimg'))
```

Comment: do I need to import time? And how to I get back to the page with the 60 products listed?

Comment: yes. you will need import time. you can use driver.back() to navigate back. However you will have to maintain a running list of 60 products and find the element to click every time when you navigate back. This is to avoid stale element exception.

Comment: dont use a fixed sleep()